# How to import csv to mysql table?

Tags: mysql, csv, import

Error: This query is just inserting the 1 line of file

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.csv' INTO TABLE coords FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

And the file has 300k lines.

Columns are separeted by commas.

Comment: Did you mean '/n' or '\n'?

Comment: \n sorry, my mistake. -1 already lol

Comment: @mbratch, My file has 300k lines, it looks like this: `1,914,26,5,53.2058,4.4162,195,-128,16.9,1230768055` which commas are separating fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is the `coords` created? Does it have 10 attributes for the data?

I just ran a quick test with a file containing six identical lines (using your data) and entered:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.csv' INTO TABLE coord FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

It read all 6 lines in.

I did this under Linux. If you're on Windows maybe you need '\r\n' (?).